# How to prevent symbols in an environment variable from escaping?

Tags: shell-script, quoting

I'm trying to write a shell script, and to make it more or less readable, i decided to bring a part of my commands into environment variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Variables

name_expression="-type d \( -name .folder1 -o -name .wildcardfolder* -o -name .folder2 \)"

# Commands

find /root/ -maxdepth 1 "$name_expression" -execdir rm -rf {} \;
find /home/ -maxdepth 2 "$name_expression" -execdir rm -rf {} \;
```

The problem is that if i try to run this shell, many symbols are wrapped with quotes:

```
bash -x ./my_shell.sh 
+ name_expression='-type d \( -name .android -o -name .AndroidStudio* -o -name .gradle \)'
+ find /home/ /root/ -maxdepth 2 '-type d \( -name .folder1 -o -name .wildcardfolder* -o -name .folder2 \)' -execdir rm -rf '{}' ';'
find: unknown predicate `-type d \( -name .folder1 -o -name .wildcardfolder* -o -name .folder2 \)'
```

Is there any way to pass this variable without being modified?

Comment: See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)  This is one of the very few cases where you *shouldn't* use double quotes when calling the variable.  But using the `*` in there is going to be dangerous.

Comment: @Wildcard Actually, this is one of the common cases where you should use double quotes (because of the wildcards, among other reasons), but you can't store a *list of strings* in a string variable.

Comment: @Gilles, that's what I was trying to convey.  See my answer and comments below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
name_expression=( -type d \( -name .folder1 -o -name .wildcardfolder\* -o -name .folder2 \) )

find /root/ -maxdepth 1 "${name_expression[@]}" -execdir rm -rf {} \;
```

Instead of a string parameter which would have to be unquoted in order for the command to see several parts, this uses an array parameter. That way both the splitting and the quoting can be controlled (not completely i.e. per part but in a suitable way for this task).

An alternative which allows complete control would be the use of `eval` but that would make the rest of the command line more complicated.

Comment: The backslash in `.wildcardfolder\*` doesn't do what you think it does.  The glob can still be expanded (to files with a backslash in the name) and the `-name` primary won't match the way it was intended.

Comment: @Wildcard I have not found an explanation for it but bash 4.4.12 does **not** expand `touch 'bar\_' ;  testvar="bar\*" ; echo $testvar bar\\*`. Does not remove the `\\` either. Maybe a shell bug.

Comment: Interesting.  You're right, it doesn't expand.  However, it *does* get treated as an escape by `find` so that `find` will only match a literal `*` character for that position.  So this command still won't work.

Comment: While I personally agree this is the proper way to address the issue, some explanation would be good so people understand what this is doing.

Comment: (Note: the comments above refer to the earlier revision of this answer, but they contain interesting relevant technical data so shouldn't be deleted IMO.)

Answer (score 2):

A modified version that avoids potentially hazardous glob expansions:

```
cleanupdir() {
  # args should be dirname, maxdepth
  find "$1" -maxdepth "$2" -type d \( -name .folder1 -o -name '.wildcardfolder*' -o -name .folder2 \) -execdir rm -rf {} \;
}

cleanupdir /root 1
cleanupdir /home 2
```